# Call an external .Net C# webapi in .net Console app, but the connection gives an error whenever I trty to Connect

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

The webapi I made is to access an sql server database using web requests to preform CRUD operations.

I created the web api as an ASP.NET Web Application(.net framework). This works fine, my controller displays the json file in the browser showing all the entries in the database. But the trouble comes when I try to access the webapi that was created in my .net console app that is in the same solution.

This is the code for my console app that shows how I'm attempting to use the web api. I am very new to the C# language and web api, I put together this test web api to just become accustom to the process, so my code is what i stitched together from reading the documentation provided and video tutorials, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
...
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;


namespace HttpClientSample
{
    #region snippet_prod
    public class Product
    {
        public string PrimaryId { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public decimal points { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }
    #endregion

    class Program
    {
        #region snippet_HttpClient
        static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        #endregion

        static void ShowProduct(Product product)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {product.Username}\tPrice: " +
                $"{product.points}\tCategory: {product.DisplayName}");
        }

        #region snippet_CreateProductAsync
        static async Task<Uri> CreateProductAsync(Product product)
        {
            //HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
            //  "api/Student", product);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/Student", new StringContent(
                new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(product), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            // return URI of the created resource.
            return response.Headers.Location;
        }
        #endregion

        #region snippet_GetProductAsync
        static async Task<Product> GetProductAsync(string path)
        {
            Product product = null;
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                string contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                product = (Product)jss.Deserialize(contentString, typeof(Product));
            }
            return product;
        }
        #endregion

        #region snippet_UpdateProductAsync
        static async Task<Product> UpdateProductAsync(Product product)
        {
           // HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
             //   $"api/Student/{product.PrimaryId}", product);

            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/Student/{product.PrimaryId}", new StringContent(
                jss.Serialize(product), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            // Deserialize the updated product from the response body.



            string contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            product = (Product)jss.Deserialize(contentString, typeof(Product));

            return product;
        }
        #endregion

        #region snippet_DeleteProductAsync
        static async Task<HttpStatusCode> DeleteProductAsync(string id)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.DeleteAsync(
                $"api/Student/{id}");
            return response.StatusCode;
        }
        #endregion

        static void Main()
        {
            RunAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        #region snippet_run
        #region snippet5
        static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            // Update port # in the following line.
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44378/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            #endregion

            try
            {
                // Create a new product
                Product product = new Product
                {
                    Username = "Gizmo",
                    points = 100,
                    DisplayName = "Widgets"
                };

                var url = await CreateProductAsync(product);
                //Console.WriteLine($"Created at {url}");
                /*
                // Get the product
                product = await GetProductAsync(url.PathAndQuery);
                ShowProduct(product);


                // Update the product
                Console.WriteLine("Updating price...");
                product.points = 80;
                await UpdateProductAsync(product);

                // Get the updated product
                product = await GetProductAsync(url.PathAndQuery);
                ShowProduct(product);

                // Delete the product
                var statusCode = await DeleteProductAsync(product.PrimaryId);
                Console.WriteLine($"Deleted (HTTP Status = {(int)statusCode})");
                */
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
#endregion
...
```

From what ive tried so far, I believe the problem has something to do with my console app trying to access the localhost url that is created when I run the debug for my WebApi project, but because I can't have both running at the same time for debugging it has nothing to access. From the tutorials that I watched, they always used online webapi that were already created by someone else, to show the CRUD operations. Does my webapi need a dedicated url and/or always need to be running in order for my console app to be able to access the json created by it? Once again I am very new to this, so I'm trying to wrap my head around the logic. The console app I created seems to only access the webapi through the url it creates, but otherwise it has no interaction, and this seems not right. Once again, any tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You can have more than one startup application in Visual Studio, but let's start with - *what is the error message*?

Comment: .NET's HTTP classes don't care whether they are called by a console or web application. Given what you posted it's impossible to guess what the error is. Of course, if the service isn't working, you can't call it. Just start the service before starting the console application.

Comment: Sorry I had to take some of the code out of the try-catch block to see exactly what the error code was. I'm getting 2 errors when I run the above code. 1. Is that my program is unable to connect to remote server, and the other is a socket error that says "no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Comment: when you say start the service before starting the console application how does that work? Currently my web api is in the same solution as my console app. So, should I start the debugger for the web api before I start the debugger for my console app?

Answer (score 0):

> but because I can't have both running at the same time for debugging it has nothing to access.

According to the current description, this issue is caused by the console app is calling a webapi which is not running at that time.
To start 2 projects at the same time in VS, please refer to [How to: Set multiple startup projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2019).
Right click your solution in Solution Explorer, choose the projects you want to run at the same time in Startup Project.